# Unable to add class to body

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have tried in all the possible ways I found googl-ing but was always unsuccesful. What I'm trying to achieve is to make the bar of the PC version be always like the Mobile version. [This](http://www.giacomovico.it) is the site I'm modifying. I've already tried using `body_class('mobile');` and the `add_filter()` methods. I wanted to add the mobile class because what I noticed while working on it is that what changes between the mobile and PC version is that class and a few other things I was altready able to change. Any suggestion. Oh, the Theme I'm using is the [Salient from NectarTheme](http://www.salienttheme.com).

**EDIT 1**

From the *header.php* class:

```
<body <?php body_class( 'test' ); ?> data-footer-reveal="<?php echo $footer_reveal; ?>" data-footer-reveal-shadow="<?php echo $footer_reveal_shadow; ?>" data-button-style="<?php echo $button_styling; ?>" data-header-inherit-rc="<?php echo (!empty($options['header-inherit-row-color']) && $options['header-inherit-row-color'] == '1' && $perm_trans != 1) ? "true" : "false"; ?>" data-header-search="<?php echo $headerSearch; ?>" data-animated-anchors="<?php echo (!empty($options['one-page-scrolling']) && $options['one-page-scrolling'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-ajax-transitions="<?php echo (!empty($options['ajax-page-loading']) && $options['ajax-page-loading'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-full-width-header="<?php echo $fullWidthHeader; ?>" data-slide-out-widget-area="<?php echo ($sideWidgetArea == '1') ? 'true' : 'false';  ?>" data-loading-animation="<?php echo (!empty($options['loading-image-animation'])) ? $options['loading-image-animation'] : 'none'; ?>" data-bg-header="<?php echo $bg_header; ?>" data-ext-responsive="<?php echo (!empty($options['responsive']) && $options['responsive'] == 1 && !empty($options['ext_responsive']) && $options['ext_responsive'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-header-resize="<?php echo $headerResize; ?>" data-header-color="<?php echo (!empty($options['header-color'])) ? $options['header-color'] : 'light' ; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($options['transparent-header']) && $options['transparent-header'] == '1') ? null : 'data-transparent-header="false"'; ?> data-smooth-scrolling="<?php echo $options['smooth-scrolling']; ?>" data-permanent-transparent="<?php echo $perm_trans; ?>" data-responsive="<?php echo (!empty($options['responsive']) && $options['responsive'] == 1) ? '1'  : '0' ?>" >
```

**EDIT 2**

I've tried to manually set the classes in the header file... well, it doesn't work even this way! I really don't know how to do!

**EDIT 3**

Ok, found the solution for the menu, but still I can't understand why my chenges weren't working! (www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzsSTnmGYAQ)

Comment: What does the current `body` tag code look like in the header file? Because you are getting classes on your body, probably from the code the theme developer added. `home page page-id-101 page-template-default custom-background test wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.7 vc_responsive`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to set the body class outside the `header.php` file.

Try doing like this:
`php
<body <?php body_class('mobile')?>>`

Comment: No, that's exactly the point! I've done that in the header.php file (as the guide told me) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a `body` filter. In your functions.php file, add:

```
function body_class_mobile( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'mobile';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_mobile');
```

This will add the `mobile` class to your `body` tag. Modify with conditionals, etc. as necessary.

Comment: That isn't working either. I've already tried, but it doesn't modify the body classes
**P.S.:** shouldn't it be `add_filter( 'body_class', 'body_class_mobile' );` as the name of the function?

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo. I've fixed it. It looks like you have the mobile class added at the end of your body class on your link `<body class="page page-id-206 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar custom-background test wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.7 vc_responsive customize-support mobile"`. Is your issue resolved?

Comment: not yet. I've tried both your and Feld Liscia's code, but it didn't work. I've tried setting the classes manually to see if it would change them in this way too... and it actually did. I've searched in all the files, but didn't find the one that might cause this.